# File 'BluetoothController.swift' is part of module 'CoreBluetooth'; ignoring import

Tags: swift, import, core-bluetooth

I am trying to create a class that uses CoreBluetooth. When I tried to import, I got this error:

[image: File 'BluetoothController.swift' is part of module 'CoreBluetooth'; ignoring import.]

Why is this happening? I also get the error if I try to import CoreBluetooth into `ViewController.swift`.

I don't get the error for other modules:

[image: Other modules don't have errors]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather hilarious really.

I named my project `CoreBluetooth`. That was what was causing the problem.

Lesson: Don't name your project after a framework or module!

Comment: omfg. lol I named my project WatchConnectivity just for testing purposes and I had about 50 of these error messages and was checking EVERYWHERE. I was about to jump off the roof of my building.

Answer (score 0):

There is already a file called BluetoothController.swift, which is a part of the CoreBluetooth framework. You probably have another file in your project with the same name.

Try finding that file and renaming it.

Comment: Then why do I get the error in `ViewController.swift`?

Comment: I figured out my problem. See my answer.